# Pandas rounding high value when reading .csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I am reading with pd.read_csv files in the order of millions of records, I have found that pandas rounds up big integer numbers such as 999999999 to 1000000000. When 999999999 is a dummy variable and not a real number this creates some issues in the analysis. I tried some options but all the documentation I have found is in relation with the rounding of floating numbers not integers. pd.read_csv function documentation does not account for this either (as far as I have found).

Do you have any idea of how to avoid this behavior?

Thanks advance

Comment: Can you try setting the `dtype` of that column as `object`? It should be like this:
`pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'column_name': object})`. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: I think you might have to use `pd.set_eng_float_format` the way it is described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#number-formatting)

Comment: did you solve this?